# Como criar constante de Objecto em javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Quero criar Objecto que não possa ser **alterado**, **redefinido** ou **removido**. O objectivo é fazer com objectos não possam ser alterados por acidente ou intencionalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinando writable:false e configurable:false, você pode essencialmente criar uma constante (não pode ser **alterada**, **redefinida** ou **removida**) como uma propriedade de objeto, como:

```
var myObject = {};

Object.defineProperty( myObject, "FAVORITE_NUMBER", {
    value: 42,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
} );
```

> Mas, isso não garante que possam adicionar novas propreidades ao
>   objecto.

Se você quiser prevenir que um objeto tenha novas propriedades adicionadas a ele, mantendo apenas o resto das propriedades do objeto, chame `Object.preventExtensions(..)`:

```
var myObject = {
    a: 2
};

Object.preventExtensions( myObject );

myObject.b = 3;
myObject.b; // undefined
```

> No `non-strict` mode a criação de b falha silenciosamente. No strict
>   mode é lançado um `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um proxy para observar modificações no objeto, e caso haja, subir um erro:

```js
function createConstant(obj) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        set() {
            throw new Error("You cannot change the object.");
        }
    });
}

const obj = createConstant({a: 1});
obj = {}; // Error
obj.a = 1; // Error
obj.b = 1; // Error
obj.a = null // Error
obj = null // Error
```

Lembrando que ainda sim a variável poderá ser removida pelo gerenciador de memória, caso isso seja indesejado você terá que criar essa variável dentro do objeto global. Não recomendo, o ideal é tentar se comportar aos escopos.